# Android ACTION_VIEW , how to open native player in landscape mode?

Tags: android, android-intent, actionview

In my app, there is a webview which user may click on a video url. Native player comes top and user can watch the video. However it always opens in PORTRAIT mode. I want video to start in LANDSCAPE  mode. How can i achieve this?

```
if(url.endsWith(".mp4")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);  
                return true;
            } else {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start a new activity, it is set to LANDSCAPE in manifest.

```
Intent intent= getIntent();
String uriString = intent.getExtras().getString("videouri");
VideoView video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uriString));

video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            finish();

        }
    });
```